# Any mapping of a surface into a 3-manifold is homotopic to an immersion

Tags: geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Let $f:S \to M$ be a singular map of  a closed surface into a compact 3-manifold $M$, then $f$ is homotopic to an immersion. 
I have seen this stated a few times without a proof, I was wondering if anybody could provide me with a reference where this statement is proved.

Thanks.

Comment: I feel you like you could first homotope it to a piecewise linear map, then use general position arguments to ensure that no two of the finitely many triangles have the same "slope".  similarly you could probably first homotope to a smooth map then use general position (Sard's theorem, etc) to ensure that it actually ends up as an immersion.  I have no reference though.

Answer (score 1):

This is proven in Lemma 1.2 in

[Immersions of surfaces in 3-manifolds](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938385900485), by J.Hass, J.Hughes, 
Topology, Volume 24, Issue 1, 1985, Pages 97-112.